# Как организовать (улучшить) структуру моделей со связями?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, инспекция-кода

Есть модель `User.js`:

```
app.factory('User', function($http, Settings, ..., AnotherModel) {

    var settings, 
        instance = {
            inited: false,
            loading: false,
            // ...
            anotherData: ...,
            behaviorMethod1: function(params) {
                // ...
            },
            behaviorMethod2: function() {
                // ...
            }
        };

    return function(){

        if(instance.inited || instance.loading) return instance;

        instance.loading = true;
        $http.get('/user').then(function(response) {
            angular.extend(instance, response.data);
            instance.settings = new Settings();
            // ...
            instance.anotherModel = new AnotherModel();
        });

        var loaded = 0,
            countLoaded = function() {
                loaded++;
                if(loaded == n) {
                    instance.inited = true;
                    instance.loading = false;
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('user:loaded');
                }
            };

        $rootScope.$on('settings:loaded', countLoaded);
        // ...
        $rootScope.$on('anotherModel:loaded', countLoaded);

        $rootScope.$on('settings:save', function() {
            instance.settings = new Settings();
        });

        // ...

        $rootScope.$on('anotherModel:event', function() {
            instance.anotherModel = new AnotherModel();
        });

        return instance;
    };
});
```

У нее есть несколько зависимостей (порядка 10-20) вида, как например, `Settings.js`:

```
app.factory('Settings', function($http, $rootScope, ...) {

    var instance = {
        inited: false,
        loading: false,
        // ...
        anotherData: ...,
        behaviorMethod1: function() {
            // ...
        },
        save: function() {
            $http.put('/settings', instance, function() {
                // ...
                instance.inited = false;
                $rootScope.$broadcast('settings:save');
            });
        }
    };

    return function() {

        if(instance.inited || instance.loading) return instance;

        instance.loading = true;
        $http.get('/settings').then(function(response) {
            // ...
            angular.extend(instance, response.data);
            instance.inited = true;
            instance.loading = false;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('settings:loaded');
        });

        return instance;
    };
});
```

В целом, данная реализация справляется со своими обязанностями, если бы не одно но: приходится ожидать до полной загрузки всех relations данной модели и возрастает количество запросов к серверу. ЗАТО! Не приходится каждый раз, когда меняется какая-нибудь из relations загружать все данные заново, а только подгружать их часть - это уменьшает количество запросов к БД. Вопрос: на ваш взгляд, что здесь не так? Что можно улучшить?

Для справок - не все из запросов к серверу означают CRUD действия и не всегда могут вернуть измененные данные, а перезагружать модель после таких действий приходится.

Comment: в чем смысл возвращать из factory функцию?

Comment: Возможно, я не прав, но мне нужен конструктор, чтобы в нем прописать загрузку модели и сделать объект синглтоном.

Comment: да, ты не прав - то, что возвращает factory уже синглтон.